# ffmpeg audio video separate files 1 command

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to get ffmpeg to output separate audio and video files in 1 command.

Here are the 2 commands I have:

```
ffmpeg -ss 04:53 -i ./07.mkv -t 3 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -filter:v "setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, crop=960:720, scale=480:360" -an -sws_flags lanczos -fflags +genpts 07-alexFlex.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 04:53 -i ./07.mkv -t 3 07-alexFlex.mp3
```

Is there a way to get it in 1 command? Ideally both the audio and video files would share the same name automatically without me changing it twice in both commands. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daisychain the commands, so

```
ffmpeg -ss 04:53 -i ./07.mkv -t 3 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -filter:v "setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, crop=960:720, scale=480:360" -an -sws_flags lanczos -fflags +genpts 07-alexFlex.mp4 -ss 04:53 -i ./07.mkv -t 3 07-alexFlex.mp3
```

Comment: Is there any way to set variables so that the file names could be copied? Like 07-alexFlex.

Comment: Sure, with simple shell scripting. It's been years since I used Linux but bash scripts should work. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/Introduction/Introduction.html - I'm sure someone will come along and provide the specific script for your current use case.